# How do I make a git branch's upstream reference be read-only?

Tags: git, readonly

How can I tell git that while I want to allow "git fetch" on certain branches that I do not want to allow "git push" on those branches.

In other words, I have some branches which reflect "current work" and I want to push them to my upstream repository.  But I have other branches (including master) which I intend to reflect "other work" in the context of the local repository, and I do not want to be stepping on those branches from here.

This is my remote repository, and in other contexts I want to be able to push into all of its branches.  But not from this specific local instance.

I think that this is possible, because git remote show origin has told me at times that I have had branches configured for "git pull" but not for "git push".  But I do not understand the config files well enough to create this effect manually, and I do not understand git's command line language well enough to do it there, either.

Right now, the best I can do is make sure that my local copy is out of date for upstream branches which I want to remain pristine.  (Also, specifying the receiving branch explicitly in my git push command line -- specifying that I only want to push into the remote instance corresponding to the locally checked out branch -- prevents pushing into undesired branches.  But I would like to eliminate that complication.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prohibit remote pushing to the master branch in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045329/prohibit-remote-pushing-to-the-master-branch-in-git)

Comment: It looks like the resolution there was to set receive.denycurrentbranch on the receiving repository.  But I am looking for control on the transmitting repository, instead.

Comment: You could set `push.default = upstream`, and then a `git push` would without additional arguments only push the locally-checked-out branch. That's looking to be the default behavior in the next release of `git`.

Comment: Do I need a specific version of git for this to work?  I tried git config --add push.default upstream but then when I tried a trial change, I get:


`$ git add README`


`error: Malformed value for push.default: upstream`


`error: Must be one of nothing, matching, tracking or current.`

Comment: (Anyways, I am not completely sure what upstream does, but it looks like push.default = tracking does the right thing for me: If I have not declared locally that an upstream branch is tracking my local branch, I cannot use a bare 'git push' to propagate to it.)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Borealid to said in the comments, in your local copy you should set `git config push.default upstream`, and then additionally make sure that those branches that you don't want to be able to push to not have an upstream branch assigned. There's a `git branch --set-upstream` command, but that won't let you set an empty upstream configuration in order to delete it, so you'll have to manually edit you .git/config file and remove the `merge = refs/heads/*` line from the sections of the corresponding branches.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like push.default = current will do what I want.

That's not precisely what I asked for, but it's "good enough". AND it has the advantage of being simple.

Simplicity is a virtue -- makes understanding and using the system straightforward.

It also closely mimics the behavior I think I am seeing from git pull.

Comment: Quoting from `git help config`: "tracking - deprecated synonym for upstream.".

Comment: Ok, which version does this start happening in?  (And why break existing documentation and so on?)